# find と sed で複数ファイルを一括置換する場合、「渡す文字列の長さ」と「結果が表示されるまでの速度」には関係がありますか？

Tags: unix

> /var/www/html/lib/a/b/c/filename_x.php

上記を下記へ置換する場合、「ファイル名だけを指定する場合」と「フルパスを指定する場合」で置換実行処理速度に違いはありますか？

> /var/www/html/lib/a/b/c/filename_z.php

・長い文字列の方が見つけやすい気もするし、短い文字列の方が処理が軽い気もするし、違いがあれば知りたいと思い質問しました

---

ファイル名だけを指定する場合の一例

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's%filename_x.php%filename_z.php%g' {} +
```

フルパスを指定する場合の一例

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's%/var/www/html/lib/a/b/c/filename_x.php%/var/www/html/lib/a/b/c/filename_z.php%g' {} +
```

Comment: 実際の環境で試した結果はどうなりましたか？

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/4236)に陥っているように見受けられます。解決したい課題を見極め直すことをお勧めします。

Comment: 「/var/www/html/」以下に対する置換処理を何度もする必要があり、待っている時間を少しでも減らしたい、と思い質問しました。後は単純に、何れが早いのか仕組み自体に興味がありました

Answer (score 4, accepted):

どちらが速いかは`sed`の実装しだいです。素直な正規表現マッチングをしていたらパターンが短い方が速いでしょうし、最適化でBM法を使っていたらパターンが長い方が速いことがあります。

いずれにしても、体感できるような差が出ることは稀ですので、悩んでいる時間があったらどちらでもいいから実行してしまえば良いと思います。

Comment: ＞sedの実装しだい。その点を知りたく思い質問しました。「体感できるような差が出ることは稀ですので」そうなのですね。納得しました

Answer (score 2):

`time` コマンドでミリ秒単位で測定出来るので 試してみてください。

実行方法: time 実行したいコマンド 引数 ...

出力例:

```
real    0m0.001s  ← 終了するまでの時間
user    0m0.000s  ← 実行したプログラムの処理にかかった時間
sys     0m0.000s  ← カーネルなどのOSの処理にかかった時間
```

Comment: 一般的にはこうする、みたいな定石があるのかと思い質問しました。最終的には実行する環境で測るしかないわけですね。しかし、検索ではなくて置換処理なので(置換後戻せない場合もあるため)、ちょっと比較しづらいな、とは思いました

Answer (score 0):

全然違う動作をするもの（の動作時間）を比較しても仕方ないんぢゃ・・・

`/var/www/html/lib/a/b/c/filename_x.php` を
`/var/www/html/lib/a/b/c/filename_z.php` に置換したいけど
`/filename_x.php` を
`/filename_z.php` に置換したくないなら後者でないと案件に合いませんよね。
逆に置換したいなら前者。

要望に合わないものを実行しても役に立たないっす。

`sed` はあなたの要望を斟酌しませんから、前者なら
`/var/www/html/lib/filename_x.php/a/b/c/filename_x.php` を
`/var/www/html/lib/filename_z.php/a/b/c/filename_z.php` に置換しますよ。

どういう置換がお望みかは読者にはわかりません。もしかしたら正規表現どちらも希望通りでないかもしれないっす。

Comment: 「/filename_x.php」を「/filename_z.php」に置換したいです。質問時点で記載していなくて大変恐縮ですが、「/filename_x.php」に関する記述は全て「/var/www/html/lib/a/b/c/filename_x.php」となっている、という前提です。